# jQuery Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I was making a progress bar for my website. But O just can't figure how to reset the bar after it loads 100%. 
What I need is when someone clicks on connect the bar should start to fill itself and when it reaches 100% to stay there and when the user clicks on connect again it should start over from 0 again.

[Here](http://goo.gl/81nx7G) you can check how it works. Please I need help I am still a beginner at this I would be thankful for any kind of help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you'll enable the buttons after the loading is complete. So add before the animation and when the animation ends you set it to `true`

```
$start.attr('disabled', false);
$stop.attr('disabled', false);
```

The you'll want that every time the animation starts the bar should reset with the message + colors

```
var $bar = $('#bar').width(0).css('background-color', 'yellow');
$message.text('Not Connected').css('color', 'red');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4prjz/4/

Comment: Can you tell me how can i make that when it second times loads that it change the #message into something else, from connected to Successful !

Comment: @user3144234 you could try it with a counter I guess ... http://jsfiddle.net/4prjz/12/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i have made simple changes to your code, though its not the best way to solve the issue, but for time being this works.

```
$bar.width(0);
$bar.css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

finally

```
Harloge = function(width){
```

Click here for [Modified code](http://jsfiddle.net/4prjz/9/)

Answer (score -1):

the progress bar stay on 100% when it's finished and then start from zero again when user click again the connect button.